# Toilet bowl fills and overflows but the tank won't fill

Tags: toilet, overflow

toilet bowl fills and will overflow while my tank wont fill up , what is the problem?   is this a plugged up toilet?  I tried the plugger it but not doing anything 
..  a couple of hrs later the bowl will empty

Comment: Bowl overflow = plugged toilet for 100% sure. The real enigma is that you state the tank won't fill, so how is it that the bowl fills with water until it overflows...?

Comment: The flapper is probably stuck open, so water runs continually into the bowl.

Comment: when the tank fills the bowl fills at the same time...causingan overflow so ineed to shut water off

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there are two problems.  You seem to have a clog in the sewer line slowing the flow of water.  You said it finally drains after a while.

You also said the tank won't fill.  This sounds like either the flapper is not seating properly, there is a leak between the bowl and tank, or the float has stopped working.

You might need to snake the sewer line if a plunger isn't working.  For the flapper and float, those may need to be replaced.  Mine seem to go out after about 4-5 years.